# Stopping a python thread while the queue is not empty

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have some code which I hopefully boiled down to a correct MWE.
My goal is to stop the (multiple) threads if a list within the thread has a specific length.
In contrast to the MWE it is not known how many iterations are needed:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def is_even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0

class MT(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.output = []

    def run(self):
        while len(self.output) < 4:
            task = self.queue.get()
            if is_even(task):
                self.output.append(task)
                self.queue.task_done()
            else:
                self.queue.task_done()
        print(self.output)
        print('done')

queue = Queue(10)

threads = 1

thr = []

for th in range(threads):
    thr.append(MT(queue))

for th in thr:
    th.start()


for i in range(100):
    queue.put(i)


queue.join()


for th in thr:
    th.join()

print('finished')
```

This code wil not hit finish...

Comment: For people like me that are not aware of the abbreviation: MWE = Minimal Working Example

Answer (score 0):

To quote the documentation,

> Queue.join()
>
> Blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.

You have placed 100 items in the queue. The thread pulls 4 items, and completes. There are still 96 unprocessed items, and nobody is going to pull them. Therefore, `queue.join()` never returns.